# Momentjs returning date that is two days behind the actual date

Tags: date, momentjs

I am trying to parse the following date string `22-04-2017`. Here is my code

```
var date = moment.parseZone($scope.booking.startDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format();

$scope.booking.startDate is 22-04-2017
```

But I am getting the following date `2017-04-20T22:13:00-20:17`. I don't care for the time, I just need the date to be correct.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead of [`parseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) since your input does not contains time zone information.

As the [`parseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) docs says:

> Moment normally interprets input times as local times (or UTC times if `moment.utc()` is used). However, often the input string itself contains time zone information. `#parseZone` parses the time and then sets the zone according to the input string.

Here a working sample:

```js
// Mocking input value
var $scope = {
  booking: {
    startDate: '22-04-2017'
  }
};
var date = moment($scope.booking.startDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format();
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```